# Calculate the average value of $f(x)=6x sec^2 x$ on the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=6x\sec^2 x$ on the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$

How do I go finding out the average?

Do I find the interval and then evaluate if the value I compute is within this domain?

For example, power rule:

$$f'(x) = 6x\tan x + 6\sec^2x $$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: There's a nice formula for average value of a function $f$ continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$.  The average value of $f$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is $$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$$

Answer (score 2):

As Alvin suggested above, the average value of a function on a closed interval $[a,b]$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is defined by $$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\ dx. $$ We wish to calculate the average value of $f(x)=6x\sec ^2(x)$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}].$

Let $\rho$ denote the average value for $f$ on the above interval. Then, $$\rho=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} 6x\sec ^2(x)\ dx.$$ We will solve this integral via integration by parts.

Let $$u=6x,\ dv=\sec ^2x\ dx,\ v=\tan x,\ du=6\ dx.  $$ Then, $$ \rho= \frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}u\ dv = \frac{4}{\pi} \big(6x\tan x\ \Big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}6\tan x\ dx\big)$$ Thus, $$\rho = \frac{4}{\pi}\big(6x\tan x\ + 6\ln |\cos x|\big)\ \Big|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}. $$ I'll leave it to you to solve the rest…!